# Blender 4.0 Windows explorer thumbnail preview not working even after making it default version

Tags: customization, blend-files, windows

Blender 4.0 Windows explorer thumbnail preview not working even after making it default version.

It used to work properly, I don't know what happened and it is not working anymore. I've searched for the solution a lot but none of them worked (like making it default version and etc.).

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: So, the trouble is that when you look at blend files in File Explorer, they just show the blender icon, when you want them to show what’s in the blender scene, kind of like a video or image file would?

Answer (score 1):

There are settings for that in the user preferences:

[image]

Make sure those are OK.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response! I tried it, but unfortunately didn't work :(